# How to proper install and configure js2-mode via use-package declaration?

Tags: hooks, use-package, javascript, install, ide

I am trying to install this package called [js2-mode](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode). This is part of my effort to follow this [tutorial](https://emacs.cafe/emacs/javascript/setup/2017/04/23/emacs-setup-javascript.html).

Package documentation and tutorial are using classic installation via `package-install` as follows:

```
M-x package-install RET js2-mode RET
```

```lisp
(require 'js2-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))
    
;; Better imenu
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'js2-imenu-extras-mode)
```

However, I like `use-package` declarations to install and configure my init file. This is my attempt:

```lisp
(use-package js2-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook ((js2-mode . js2-imenu-extras-mode))
  :init
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode)))
```

It seems to be correct. Not sure if I am missing something, though.

Is this correct? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works correctly then it is correct. Otherwise it is wrong. Why do you need our approval?

Also note that `js2-mode` is included with Emacs; there is no longer any need to install it from ELPA.

Comment: It is just that I am not used to this package. And until now, I have not used iMenu.